# how to hide/show through a header button in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have added a button in header to show/hide navigation drawer. since the button and navigation drawers are in different component, which option is better to communicate?

[Sample demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nzsx7r?)

Comment: did you get a chance to look at these errors / warnings:Pro Tip: Run & debug your app in its own window --> https://angular-nzsx7r.stackblitz.io/
preview-1f727e0cbae2a3ba41a0a.js:1:16406
Could not find Angular Material core theme. Most Material components may not work as expected. For more info refer to the theming guide: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming
preview-1f727e0cbae2a3ba41a0a.js:1:11037
Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.

Comment: You can use a shared instance of a service that container a eventEmitter of use a state management library like ngrx/ngxs. I prefer the last one event for small projects

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **service** to preseve the state of the navigation bar. You can use a **Observable boolean** in the service for that. When you click the button set it to true or false. Then from the navigation bar component **subscribe** for that service property to shoe hide the contents in the navigation bar.

In your service

```
@Injectable()
export class GlobalDataService {
  private showNavigationBar = new Subject<boolean>();

  constructor() {

  }

  public getNavigationbarState(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.showNavigationBar.asObservable();
  }

  public setNavigationbarState(value: boolean) {
    return this.showNavigationBar.next(notification);
  }
}
```

In your header component button click event.

```
constructor(private globalDatServce:GlobalDataService) {

}

public onButtonClick(): void {
  this.globalDataService.setNavigationbarState(true); // pass true or false as needed
}
```

In the naviagtion bar component constructor.

```
constructor(private globalDatServce:GlobalDataService) {
   this.globalDatServce.getNavigationbarState().subscribe((res) => {
     this.shownavigation = res;
   });
}
```

In the template

```
<div *ngIf="shownavigation">
  // navigation content goes here
</div>
```

Comment: how to use drawer.toggle() ?

Comment: use it for the button click replace the `onButtonClick` with your `toggleDrawer`

Answer (score 0):

a "simplified" version of service is

```
//in header
<div *ngIf="shownavigation">....</div>

constructor(private globalDataService:GlobalDataService){}
get shownavigationn()
{
   return this.globalDataService.shownavigation
}
```

And

```
//In component
<button (click)="click()">Click me!</button>

constructor(private globalDataService:GlobalDataService){}
set shownavigationn(value)
{
   this.globalDataService.shownavigation=value
}
click()
{
    this.showNavigation=!this.showNavigation
}
```